# Increase/Descrease the SplashScreen time In XAMARIN APP

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to descrease the time of SplashScreen In **XAMARIN** plateform, Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you should create a SplashActivity page :

```
public class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity
{

    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    }

    // Launches the startup task
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        Task startupWork = new Task(() => { SimulateStartup(); });
        startupWork.Start();
    }

    // Simulates background work that happens behind the splash screen
    async void SimulateStartup ()
    {
         await Task.Delay (8000); // AND AT HERE YOU CAN DECREASE YOUR SPLASH SCREEN TIME.
         StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof (MainActivity)));
    }
}
```